# GC.KeepAlive() and System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have declered `System.Timers.Timer` object in class level and created in constructor.started the timer in another method.

In elapsed event handler enabled property set to false and excute some code and again enabled set to true.

I am getting elapsed events for each intervel.
problem is aftre some time elapsed is stoped.

I am suspecting that timer object is collected by the GC at the momment enabled property set to false in the elapsed event hanler eventhadler.

So I want my timer object set to keep alive.

Where should i declare `GC.KeepAlive(timer)` in my project?

Answer (score 5):

If the timer is declared at class level, it's not being collected automatically by the GC, because it doesn't go out of scope. And setting `Enabled` to `false` can't cause the behavior that you describe. Your problem is somewhere else.

I would suspect an exception in your event handler. `System.Timers.Timer` swallows exceptions that occur in the event handler, meaning that if an exception escapes the event handler, you'll never know about it.

I suspect your code is written similar to this:

```
myTimer.Enabled = false;
// do stuff here
myTimer.Enabled = true;
```

If an exception is thrown during the "do stuff here", the exception escapes the handler, the timer never gets re-enabled, and the timer code swallows the exception so you never know that something happened.

You should write your event handler like this:

```
myTimer.Enabled = false;
try
{
    // do stuff here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle exceptions
}
finally
{
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

You normally want to catch just specific exceptions--the ones you know how to handle. Catching all exceptions like above is generally bad practice.

Comment: I know this is an old question but i have the same problem as this but i have the code wrapped in a try catch finally as suggested here and it still seems to stop every so often. what else could be causing this?

Comment: @AdamWilson Offhand, I can't think of anything else that would cause that problem, unless some other bit of code is setting `Enabled` to `false`. My suggestion would be to post a question that includes the relevant code. Perhaps somebody else will have some insight.